# Aplicações C# .Net MVC como compartilhar login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https

Olá,

Como integrar aplicações desenvolvidas com C# .NET MVC, tendo um único login? Salvo as proporções, o que procuro é algo como o que acontece ao acessar gmail, depois acesar o googledrive ou googleCalendar e vice versa.

Obrigado,

Comment: Pesquise por SSO e IdentityServer

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é armazenar os dados do navegador do usuário no momento em que ele efetuar o primeiro login, e sempre que for necessário chamar o método de login, você captura esses dados e faz a verificação.

O problema fazendo isso é que os dados do navegador podem mudar caso o usuario limpe os cookies, ou ele acesse de um navegador diferente.

Utilize em seu controller o métoto HttpContext.Session.SessionID para capturar a SessionID do navegador do usuario.